# Can I check for multiple paragraphs in Codeception?

Tags: codeception, acceptance-testing, paragraphs

I'm using Codeception + Selenium.

On my website and in emails sometimes I have a text consisting of multiple paragraphs. I want to check all or most of them in my acceptance tests. I know I can do

`$I->canSee($par1, $locator);
$I->canSee($par2, $locator);`

however it becomes cumbersome to do this for many paragraphs.

If I try to check for more than one paragraph in canSee(), it fails.

Do you know how I can check for more than one paragraph of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  the best way   for you will be usage of "grabMultiple" ( PhpBrowser)

```
    $p = $I->grabMultiple('.article-body p');
    codecept_debug($p);
    >> [
          0 => "P1 text",
          1 => "P2 Text",
          2 => "P3 Text"
       ]
```

will give you back array of matched elements, so you can test how much of them you have, and check what text they have.